# How are these two statements in Fortran fixed-form source tokenized?

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, lexer, lexical-analysis

I am interesting in lexical analysis, especially the Maximal Munch Principle. What I currently focus on is the backtracking action. I want to know how backtracking works in the following example.

First, I know whitespace is insignificant in Fortran in fixed-form source. Thus, the following statements have different meanings.

```
      DO 5 I = 1,25
```

is a Do statement;

```
      DO 5 I = 1.25
```

is a variable assignment: DO5I = 1.25

What I was told is that in the first statement, we could not confirm whether DO or DO5I is a token until the comma is read. Does the backtracking in maximal munch work for this? If yes, how does it work? Could somebody give me all the steps of this tokenization?

Comment: Whitespace is significant if you have free-form source code.  You're second statement is invalid free-form Fortran and a compiler may generate a syntax error.

Comment: To put it another way while fixed format Fortran is still standard for backwards compatibility reasons, otherwise you are living 30+ years in the past

Comment: Although this "do or assignment?" question is a famous example, it's really not a special case in lexing Fortran (or other languages).  Even `real x` in fixed-form source can't be lexed without further context and neither can `end ` in either form.